# How to request Admin App rights in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

It has been asked several times here within Stackoverflow, but unfortunately the solutions does not apply to Android 12 or higher.

I have a remote wipe function running in my foreground that is triggered online.
This works properly, but now I have to use the ADB every time to assign the admin rights to the app.
I would like to arrange this from the app it self. But this seems easier said than done.
Here is an example of my Manifest that I am using.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.hello.chatreal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCK_DEVICE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ChatReal"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <service android:name=".SampleForegroundService"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".LockscreenActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".NotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".HangUp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".DeviceAdminReceiverClass"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the function "requestAdminRights" that I call in my Activity.

```
 var startActivityIntent: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> {
            Log.d("debug", it.toString())
        })

    fun requestAdminRights() {
        val componentName = ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminReceiver::class.java)
        val chooserIntent = Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN).apply {
            putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, componentName)
            putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Testcase")
        }
        startActivityIntent.launch(chooserIntent)
    }
    requestAdminRights()
```

And then it returns the following line:

```
ActivityResult{resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED, data=null}
```

Is there another step I'm missing to get this working in Android 12 with Kotlin?

Comment: `ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN` [is not documented to return a result](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN).

Comment: Correct, I removed it from the code. But still the admin display screen does not show when I initiate the function.

Comment: Hmmm... try `android:exported="false"`. Since you're being bound to from a system process, I don't know if you need that to be exported, and they may not like it that you are (for security reasons). You might also double-check your `device_admin` resource, or try removing `android:priority="1000"` and unnecessary actions in the `<intent-filter>`.